# MySQL distinct sum without subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two main tables bills and billing_items:

```
bills
_______
id
..
amount
balance

billing_items
______________
id
...
bill_id
```

I need to get the sum of the bill amount and balance based on certain criteria in the billing_items table (the table references other tables of interest)

when I use the below query I get duplicates:

```
select sum(b.amount), sum(b.balance) 
from bills b left join billing_items bi 
on b.id=bi.bill_id;
```

I can't use subqueries such as the one below because of the ORM I'm using (subqueries not supported):

```
select sum(a) from 
(select b.amount as a, b.balance 
   from bills b left join billing_items bi 
   on b.id=bi.bill_id group by b.id) t;
```

the criteria on billing_items and its referencing tables is ommited but I need to reference billing_items

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: So what is wrong with the first query?  Can you explain what "certain criteria" are (as you don't have any filters in your query).  I think it would really help if you could explain in plain language what you want the result set to look like.

Comment: I will be inner joining billing_items with 3 other tables (visitprocedure -> visit -> referrer -> company) I need to filter the company.id

Comment: VIEWS are not ideal, I need a solution with minimal code changes

Comment: can you use @variables in your SQL and ORDER BY? that might be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if your ORM allows the use of user variables or not in your SQL, if yes you could try this, basically it's `ORDER BY bi.bill_id` and only sum amount when there's a new `bill_id`

```
select sum(IF (@prevBillId IS NULL OR @prevBillId != bi.bill_id,b.amount,0)) as sumAmount, 
       sum(IF (@prevBillId IS NULL OR @prevBillId != bi.bill_id,b.balance,0)) as sumBalance,
       @prevBillId:=bi.bill_id
from bills b left join billing_items bi 
on b.id=bi.bill_id
ORDER BY bi.bill_id;
```

see this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dd730/5/1)

Comment: The ORM does not but this is a great solution.  Unfortunately I can't use it

Comment: does your ORM allow you to use NOT EXIST(SELECT from sometable WHERE somecolumn=somevalue)?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work...

So your issue is your left join to billing_items is causing multiple rows per billing item and your sum(b.amount) is being multiplied by the number of rows you have.  So solution...divide your sum by your count.

```
select b.id,sum(b.amount) / count(*) as amount, sum(b.balance) 
from bills b left join billing_items bi 
on b.id=bi.bill_id;
group by b.id
```

Give that a try...hoping it works out.

Comment: I like the idea but it can't work.  The amount of each bill is added again for every billing item in each particular bill

Comment: the amount you are summing is in the bills table correct?  When you join to billing_items, the amount of the bill is simply repeated for each billing item (or each line).  Not sure if I understand why it can't work.  If 10'000 is repeated for times, it sums to 40000 and divide by 4 is back to the 10'000 number you wanted.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you are summing here

Comment: ((100 + 100 + 100) / 3)) + ((200 + 200 + 200 + 200)/4) != 1100/7

Comment: I missed a grouping in my solution...editted in a change.  You want to group by b.id to keep the 3 100's and 4 200's seperate by ID.

Comment: Yes but this will not give a one row result